# Is there no limit to the amount of memory webkit is allowed to use?

Tags: android

I have found that if an application uses a WebView, it use more memory than is defined by [dalvik.vm.heapsize]. For example, on my device [dalvik.vm.heapsize] is 32M; the WebView application can use more memory than `50M`.

Is there no limit for Webkit's memory utilization?

Answer (score 0):

WebView is implemented in C++, directly, so it isn't subject to the VM heapsize.

Comment: but  how is the bitmap native memory  ?